# examples of chromosomal aberrations with lack of sexual chromosomes?

Tags: genetics, chromosome

Are there any examples in animals where individuals survive having no copies of their sexual chromosomes?

Comment: In humans the [Turner syndrom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turner_syndrome) is a disease that occur when the carrier is X0 (has only one sexual chromsome, the X chromsome). But it does not answer your question I guess!

Comment: Are you talking exclusively about nullisomic during the diplontic phase of an organism? Otherwise before Turner syndrome occurs in the diploid individual, one gamete (haplontic phase) has to be nullisomic for a sex chromsome.